# JAX-WS client without having to generate new proxies when switching between test/production

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-ws

I'm trying to configure my JAX-WS Client to switch between test/production enpoint without having to re-generate proxy classes with wsimport.

The service I'm trying to consume use different WSDL's in test and production. For example the targetNamespace is different, as well as the soapAction address.

I've tried using Springs JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean and have managed to point to the different wsdl depending on the deployment environment, but even though I point to production, it still uses the WebMethod action addresses from test. I guess this is because they are hard-coded in the service interface that was generated using wsimport pointing to the test-wsdl.

Anyone know if it is possible to switch between wsdls using different targetNamespace and action addresses without re-generation proxies?

Comment: Looks like it's the action parameter in the media type header that is wrong. Will try to change it using a handler.

Comment: I did some digging and found out that I had to disable the action parameter in the HTTP media type header. That way I'm able to call i.e.. the production service even though the proxies were generated using the test wsdl. So my next issue is changing the namespace used in the return envelope, because the prod/test wsdl is using different namespaces causing problems in the unmarshaling. Anyone know if that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the endpoint address property:
https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/How_to_invoke_and_endpoint_by_overriding_endpoint_address_in_the_WSDL.html.

```
//Create service and proxy from the generated Service class.
HelloService service = new HelloService();
HelloPort proxy = service.getHelloPort();

<b>((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                                                    "http://new/endpointaddress");</b>

proxy.sayHello("Hello World!");
```

I'm not sure from your question if you need to override other parameters as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is not overriding the endpoint address. See comment above.